# How to remove docker proxy settings?

Tags: docker, docker-build

Please advise how to remove docker proxy settings,
I remember that I had set docker to use proxy initially and I removed file from /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d.

I am trying to execute following command

```
sudo docker build -t <image_name> .
```

Is there a way to run docker command with no_proxy using --build-arg?
Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen to [customise docker settings using systemd](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/), which is nice and all, but in that case to change those settings you will always need to restart the service.

In your case you need to use a different approach , by [using environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#use-environment-variables).

It will make your life easier, hope it helps , good luck.

Comment: Thanks Mark! restarting service worked for me
I followed, 
Flush changes and restart Docker
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker

Answer (score 2):

after removing  **http-proxy.conf**  file from **/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d.**
you have to reload daemon and restart docker service.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

you can verify how http proxy and https proxy are valued with the command below

```
sudo docker info
```

or with the command

```
sudo systemctl show --property=Environment docker
```

Comment: and be sure there isn't proxy settings in file  /etc/default/docker

Answer (score 0):

There is a section where you have activated this proxy. According to your document, there are two places to enable the proxy

https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#use-environment-variables

The first file

```
~/.docker/config.json
```

You can delete your config from there
And the second one is inside environment variables
In both cases, you must reset Docker after doing this, you can use the following commands

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart docker
```